# Pygame program runs without exceptions, but doesn't show the display

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple Pygame program, but I am having trouble getting the display to show up. The program runs without exceptions, but the display doesn't show

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

# Initialize the pygame library
pygame.init()

# Set the window title
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")

# Set the window size
screen_width = 600
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# Create the snake
snake_body = [(200, 200), (220, 200), (240, 200)]

# Create the food
food_x = 300
food_y = 200

# Set the snake's direction
snake_direction = "right"

# Set the snake's speed
snake_speed = 10

# Create a clock to keep track of time
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Start the main game loop
while True:

    # Check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break

        # Check for key presses
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                snake_direction = "left"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                snake_direction = "right"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                snake_direction = "up"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                snake_direction = "down"

    # Move the snake
    head = snake_body[0]
    if snake_direction == "left":
        head = (head[0] - snake_speed, head[1])
    elif snake_direction == "right":
        head = (head[0] + snake_speed, head[1])
    elif snake_direction == "up":
        head = (head[0], head[1] - snake_speed)
    elif snake_direction == "down":
        head = (head[0], head[1] + snake_speed)
    snake_body.insert(0, head)

    # Check if the snake hit the boundaries
    if head[0] < 0 or head[0] >= screen_width or head[1] < 0 or head[1] >= screen_height:
        break

    # Check if the snake hit the food
    if head == (food_x, food_y):
        snake_body.append((snake_body[-1][0], snake_body[-1][1]))
        food_x = random.randint(0, screen_width - 20)
        food_y = random.randint(0, screen_height - 20)

    # Check if the snake hit itself
    for i in range(1, len(snake_body)):
        if head == snake_body[i]:
            break
    else:
        continue
    break

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # Draw the snake
    for body_part in snake_body:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (body_part[0], body_part[1], 20, 20))

    # Draw the food
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (food_x, food_y, 20, 20))

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Wait for a frame
    clock.tick(60)

# End the game
pygame.quit()
```

I have checked that I have called pygame.init() and pygame.display.set_mode(). I have also checked that I am calling pygame.display.flip() periodically. I'm expecting the snake game to work.

I am not sure what else I could be doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a `break` in your `while` loop that is not indented correctly. the `else: continue break` section all needs to be indented another level. The `break` is running on the first loop iteration and so it is closing the window and ending the program immediately.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Pygame or the display. You simply have a `break` in the middle of the application loop and terminate the program immediately

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I recommend creating a new file and writing the minimal code you need to show a window with pygame. You should try to run your code frequently. Writing too much code before trying to run it always leads to lots of errors that are difficult to solve. If you run code often, then you will find these errors sooner and solve them sooner.